# jQuery Validation - Works, but doesn't "submit"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, jquery-validate

I have a form that nicely "lights up" with validation messages and changes the "Save" button to "Loading..." as it passes validation. All good.

However, the form is never submitted.

I think I am missing fundamental.

```
    $("#btnSave").on("click", function() {

        if ($("#formMain").valid()) {
            var btn = $(this);
            btn.button('loading');   //This works and fires when the form is valid
            setTimeout(function() {
                btn.button('reset');
            }, 3000);
            $("#formMain").submit();   //FireBug says this is hit, but nothing happens
        }
    });
```

In case it's my validator, here it is for reference:

```
var CloudFormValidation = function () {


var handleValidation = function() {
    // for more info visit the official plugin documentation: 
    // http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

    var form2 = $('#formMain');
    var error2 = $('.alert-danger', form2);
    var success2 = $('.alert-success', form2);

    form2.validate({
        errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
        errorClass: 'help-block', // default input error message class
        focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
        ignore: "",


        invalidHandler: function(event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit              
            success2.hide();
            error2.show();
            App.scrollTo(error2, -200);
        },

        errorPlacement: function(error, element) { // render error placement for each input type
            var icon = $(element).parent('.input-icon').children('i');
            icon.removeClass('fa-check').addClass("fa-warning");
            icon.attr("data-original-title", error.text()).tooltip({ 'container': 'body' });
        },

        highlight: function(element) { // hightlight error inputs
            $(element)
                .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group   
        },

        unhighlight: function(element) { // revert the change done by hightlight

        },

        success: function(label, element) {
            var icon = $(element).parent('.input-icon').children('i');
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success'); // set success class to the control group
            icon.removeClass("fa-warning").addClass("fa-check");
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            success2.show();
            error2.hide();
        }
    });


};




return {
    //main function to initiate the module
    init: function () {
        handleValidation();
    }

};
```

}();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Ostati and John S, you got me on the right rack. Here's the changes I made to make ti work:

My submit button (just a  )

```
    $("#btnSave").on("click", function() {
        $("#formMain").submit();  //Do this here to kick off the process

        if ($("#formMain").valid()) { //If valid the plugin will submit for real
            var btn = $(this);
            btn.button('loading');
            setTimeout(function() { btn.button('reset'); }, 3000);
      }
    });
```

Then my submit handler:

```
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            success2.show();
            error2.hide();
            form.submit();  //Must be called here,
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a different submit mechanism

```
$(this).closest("form").submit()
```

Also, can you temporarily remove the setTimeout call?

Comment: Hi, I tried that, but still no submit action. Very strange.

Comment: What if you remove all lines (including validation) inside the click handler and just call the submit function?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are supposed to submit the form in the [`submitHandler`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) method.

You could try:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $("#btnSave").button('loading');
    setTimeout(function() { $("#btnSave").button('reset'); }, 3000);
    success2.show();
    error2.hide();
    form.submit();
}
```

Then if the button is a submit button, you could remove the on-click handler. If it is not, you could change it to:

```
$("#btnSave").click(function() {
    $("#formMain").submit();
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that , but no form is submitted. I also removed all the button's animations in case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your button has the `type="submit"` attribute set.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I didn't write it for the question's author, but for all the poor souls that come here wondering why their form don't get submitted with bs.validator, even though they do get submitted without. Feel free to organize a mob of unhelpful douches to get the answer closed.