# jQuery .submit() doesn't work after i use jquery .validate() on a form

Tags: jquery, validation, submit

I got a button that triggers the form submit:

```
$('#formButton').click(function(e) {
  $('#form').submit();
)};
```

When i add a form validator, it no longer submits anything (doesn't do anything):

```
  var validate= $('#form').validate({
    "rules": {
      "name": {
         "required": true
      }
    }
  });
```

This is what i want to do but like i said the .submit() function does't do anything once i use the .valiate() function:

```
$('#formButton').click(function(e) {
  if (validate.form() === false) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    $('#form').submit();
  }
)};
```

I cant use ajax instead of .submit() because i have some inputs that has a type of 'file', and as i understand i cant `.serialize()` for such input types.

Any suggestions why the .submit() function stops submitting once i use .validate()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Validation - Works, but doesn't "submit"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21803040/jquery-validation-works-but-doesnt-submit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`validate` method prevents the default action of the `submit` event, when you submit the form the `validate` method is called. If you want to submit the form when the form fields are valid, you should define a `submitHandler` function on the passed object to the `validate` method:

```
$('#form').validate({
    "rules": {
      "name": {
         "required": true
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

As the `form` argument is a raw DOM element, calling it's `submit` method doesn't call the `validate` method. If you don't want to define the mentioned method you can get the raw DOM element using `.get()` method and call it's `submit` method:

```
$('#form').get(0).submit();
```

Comment: This is a FAQ. +1 but actually it is a huge duplicate